# Angularjs dynamic form field with select option disable already selected option

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have dynamically adding form fields with a select option. what I want is disabling the previously selected options in the new added field.
my html is like this

```
<div ng-repeat="exam_student in exam_students track by $index">

   <select 
    ng-model="exam_student.student_id"
    options="students"
    ng-options="student.id as student.sname for student in students">
  </select>
  <button type="button" ng-click="removeStudent($index)">-</button>

</div>

<button type="button" ng-click="addStudent()">+</button>
```

and my js is

```
$scope.exam_students = [{}]; 
$scope.addStudent = function(){
    $scope.exam_students.push({});
}

$scope.removeStudent = function(index){
    $scope.exam_students.splice(index,1);
}
```

Here is the Plunker
[plnkr.co/edit/VOZrqIos54IcunBTAwat](http://plnkr.co/edit/VOZrqIos54IcunBTAwat)

thank you for your any help and suggestions.

Comment: code on plunker pls

Comment: Please check https://plnkr.co/edit/VOZrqIos54IcunBTAwat

Comment: pls make it clear what is your requirement

Comment: okay let me change the plunker got your answer

Comment: here pIus sign will add the select option with student list let say josh is selected at first then josh should not be available in other added

Comment: Check the answer fiddle @sanu

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/athulnair/c3Lorjrx/

```
 $scope.filteredstudents =angular.copy($scope.students)
  $scope.addStudent = function(name){
       $scope.exam_students.push({"id":name,"sname":name});
     debugger;
     var index = $scope.filteredstudents.findIndex(item => item.id === name);
     $scope.filteredstudents.splice(index, 1);

  }

  $scope.removeStudent = function(name){
  var examstudentindex = $scope.exam_students.findIndex(item => item.id === name);
      $scope.exam_students.splice(examstudentindex,1);
    var index = $scope.students.findIndex(item => item.id === name);
    $scope.filteredstudents.push($scope.students[index]);
  }
```

otherwise you can call `$scope.filterStudents();` it will filter your array by selection

```
$scope.filterStudents = function (){
      $scope.filteredstudents = $scope.students.filter( function( el ) {
        return !$scope.exam_students.map(i=>(i.id)).includes( el.id );
      });
  }
```

Comment: yes something like this but what if user change the option

Comment: I think you can disable option in the array so that you can only remove them.